# Asset Browser works only for current file?

Tags: linux, asset-browser, library

Hey the asset browser doesn't works for me here ? I do select my models in Object Mode or select materials and mark them as Asset.
The marked assets appears in the Asset Browser section and I can add them in a fresh created category.

**The assets stay in the current blend file only and doesn't appear in my library.**
I've checked the path in the Blender preferences and created a Library with the name "User Library" - Path: /home/myusername/ProjectFiles/Blender/Assets

I also checked **the Assets folder and can see it is empty.**

I do not have any assets if I create a new Blend Project File

Using Blender version 3.2.1 on Linux

**EDITED:**
Works now! I didn't know and missed to save the .blend files which contains marked assets into my Library Assets path. Assets appears in a new created project file now

Comment: Hello, please add your solution as an answer (scroll down and enter it in the textfield on the bottom of the page) so that it can benefit other people in the future, too. Thank you :)